# How to minimize multiple sub queries using join?

Tags: sql, optimization, subquery

Can anyone come up with a better solution?

```
SELECT TITLE,BOR_NAME,BOR_ADDRESS FROM BOOK,BORROWER 
WHERE BOOKID IN 
     (SELECT BOOKID 
      FROM BOOK_LOANS 
      WHERE BRANCHID IN 
            (SELECT BRANCHID 
             FROM LIBRARY_BRANCH 
             WHERE BRANCH_NAME='SHARPSTOWN'))
      AND CARDNO IN 
          (SELECT CARDNO 
           FROM BOOK_LOANS 
           WHERE DUEDATE=to_date(sysdate));
```

Any help?

Comment: Could you please show us some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: What's the problem with current solution?

Comment: Aren't you missing a JOIN condition between BOOK and BORROWER?

Answer (score 0):

You can include the subselect into FROM section using JOIN

e.g. this way

```
SELECT TITLE,BOR_NAME,BOR_ADDRESS 
FROM 
BOOK JOIN BOOK_LOANS ON BOOK.CARDNO =BOOK_LOANS.CARDNO AND BOOK_LOANS.DUEDATE=to_date(sysdate)
,BORROWER 
WHERE BOOKID IN (SELECT BOOKID FROM BOOK_LOANS WHERE BRANCHID IN (SELECT BRANCHID FROM LIBRARY_BRANCH WHERE BRANCH_NAME='SHARPSTOWN'))
;
```

The same coul be done with another bigger subselect

Answer (score 0):

You can write as:

```
SELECT BK.TITLE,
       BRR.BOR_NAME,
       BRR.BOR_ADDRESS
FROM BORROWER BRR
left join BOOK_LOANS BL on BL.CARDNO = BRR.CARDNO
left join BOOK BK on BK.BOOKID = BL.BOOKID
left join LIBRARY_BRANCH LB on LB.BRANCHID = BL.BRANCHID
where BL.DUEDATE = to_date(sysdate)
and LB.BRANCH_NAME='SHARPSTOWN';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.title, bor.bor_name, bor.bor_address
from  book b,
      borrower bor,
      book_loans bl,
      library_banch lib,
where b.book_id       = bl.book_id
and   b.cardno        = bor.cardno 
and   bl.branch_id    = lib.branch_id
and   lib.branch_name ='SHARPSTOWN'   
and   bl.duedate = to_date(sysdate);
```

Comment: book.cardno?? do you mean self join here?

Comment: no sorry, mispelled the table - now should be right